# reading in .txt files from a directory using R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in text files from a directory and then merge the data from these files into 1 data frame. The files are 3 rows by 8125 columns. There is a bit of a challenge that I think sets this question apart from similar questions on StackOverflow in that the files (which are generated by a program I am using) lack value in position [1,1] and I wonder if this is throwing things off.

I'm not quite sure (yet) how to upload a file, so in the absence of an example file, I'll just paste a small example of the data structure here.

[image: example_data_subset picture]

Furthermore, some files may have rows in which all values are zeros. I am not sure if that is also presenting a problem. I can load the files individually, no problem, but the problem seems to come when I try and loop the process and merge them into one data frame.

This is the current code I am using:

```
list.filenames<-list.files("run2/", full.names = TRUE)

# create an empty list that will serve as a container to receive the incoming files
list.data<-list()

# create a loop to read in your data

for(i in 1:length(list.filenames)){
  file <- read.table(list.filenames[i], sep="", fill = TRUE) 
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
```

If I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

I have also tried

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list.filenames, function(x) read.delim(file=x)))
```

And this does not work either, yielding the error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
2: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

This is my first time trying to do a for loop in R or read a directory of files, so many of these errors are new to me.

Another question I have is if it would be possible to read in 1 row at a time from each file and create 3 different files for the 3 different rows. But, I am not even sure where to begin with that.

Hopefully, this question makes some semblance of sense.

Thanks a million!
colleen

Comment: `sep=""` is probably wrong, try to open your file with something else than Excel, with Notepad for example and look at what is between the columns (comma, semi colon, tab...)

Comment: Try `data.table::fread("path/to/file.txt")` without further arguments, it often works well. Then you can `data.table::rbindlist`

Comment: have you tried using the `rio` package?

Comment: @fmarm when I try sep="\t" i get the same error messages, so that did't seem to help.

Comment: @BerndKonfuzius if i try to use the `rio` package (`test<-import_list(dir("run2/", pattern = ".txt"))`), i just get a bunch of warnings: `Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Import failed for July.KC10.100m.feature_table.txt
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Import failed for July.KC10.150m.feature_table.txt
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Import failed for July.KC10.200m.feature_table.txt
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Import failed for July.KC10.25m.feature_table.txt`

Comment: @colleen - welcome to StackOverflow. One way to solve your problem is to use an R function that allows you to skip the first row of data to avoid the problem with the missing column header for the first column of data. See the answer I've posted for one way to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two requirements to solve with this question. First, we need to read a set of files that have the same columns, where the files are stored in a subdirectory with the file extension `.txt`. Columns in the data file are separated by a delimiter character whose value isn't specified in the OP.

Second, each file is missing a column heading for what appears to be a column called `location` or `type`.

The second consideration makes it difficult to use a standard R function to read the file, because most of the raw data file reader functions expect a column name for every column in the raw data file, if the file is to be processed with the `header = TRUE` argument.

We'll use the `readr::read_csv()` function to solve this problem, because `readr::read_csv()` allows us to specify the rows to be read from a data file.

Specifically, we'll read the column names from one file, add a `location` column name, and then read the entire set of data files to avoid using the first row, and to not set the first row as column names.

We replicated the data in the post and saved two copies of it to data files in a `\data` subdirectory of the current R working directory. We used `,` as the delimiter to make it visible in the example data.

The data looks like this:

```
OTU9,OTU6,OTU1972,OTU39,OTU1456,OTU16,OTU58,OTU5
Soil,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Stream,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Unknown,100,0,20,80,0,70,0,70
```

Note that if the data field separator in the actual data is a character other than `,`, one can specify the correct separator character in `read_csv()` with the `delim=` argument.

## Step 1: retrieve the file names from the subdirectory

I named the files `so58176322-1.txt` and `so58176322-2.txt`, based on the Stackoverflow identifier for the original post.

```
theFiles <- list.files("./data",pattern="so5817*",full.names = TRUE)

# list the files
theFiles
```

The `theFiles` vector contains two file names.

```
> theFiles
[1] "./data/so58176322-1.txt" "./data/so58176322-2.txt"
```

## Step 2: read column names from one data file

Next, we load the `readr` package and extract the column name row from the first file in the list.

```
library(readr)

# read header row, add "location" and save to vector

columnData <- read_csv(theFiles[1],col_names = FALSE,n_max = 1)
columnNames <- unlist(c("location",as.vector(columnData[1,])))
```

## Step 3: read the data and combine into one data frame

Finally, we'll use `lapply()` with an anonymous function to read the data files, using `read_csv()` to read data starting in the second row. Once we've read the files, we'll use `do.call()` with `rbind()` to combine the files in the list generated by `lapply()` and then set the column names.

```
# read raw data from multiple files
# 
# assume that all files have the same column names, which is inferred from OP
# 

theData <- lapply(theFiles,function(x){read_csv(theFiles[1],col_names = FALSE,skip = 1)})

# at this point, theData is a list that contains two data frames
# we can now combine the data frames with rbind() and add the column names

combinedData <- do.call(rbind,theData)
# set correct column names 
colnames(combinedData) <- columnNames
combinedData
```

...and the output, showing the correct column names and all data in a single data frame.

```
> combinedData
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  location  OTU9  OTU6 OTU1972 OTU39 OTU1456 OTU16 OTU58  OTU5
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Soil         0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0
2 Stream       0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0
3 Unknown    100     0      20    80       0    70     0    70
4 Soil         0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0
5 Stream       0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0
6 Unknown    100     0      20    80       0    70     0    70
>
```

## Enhancing the solution: tracking the file names

This solution can be enhanced by adding the file name as a column in the output data, as follows.

```
theData <- lapply(theFiles,function(x){
  y<- read_csv(theFiles[1],col_names = FALSE,skip = 1)
  # add a column for source file name
  y$sourceFile <- x
  y})

# at this point, theData is a list that contains two data frames
# we can now combine the data frames with rbind() and add the column names

combinedData <- do.call(rbind,theData)
colnames(combinedData) <- c(columnNames,"sourceFile")
combinedData
```

...and the output.

```
> combinedData
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  location  OTU9  OTU6 OTU1972 OTU39 OTU1456 OTU16 OTU58  OTU5 sourceFile             
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                  
1 Soil         0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0 ./data/so58176322-1.txt
2 Stream       0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0 ./data/so58176322-1.txt
3 Unknown    100     0      20    80       0    70     0    70 ./data/so58176322-1.txt
4 Soil         0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0 ./data/so58176322-2.txt
5 Stream       0     0       0     0       0     0     0     0 ./data/so58176322-2.txt
6 Unknown    100     0      20    80       0    70     0    70 ./data/so58176322-2.txt
>
```